# storage eventlistener not working alongside any update to localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener

In my componentDidMount I am trying to remove a localstorage item and also adding an event listener for further changes in the localstorage and it is not working

```
  componentDidMount() {
    localStorage.removeItem("receivedLocation");
    window.addEventListener("storage", event => {
      console.log("Event listener triggered");
      if (event.key === "receivedLocation" && event.newValue === true) {
        this.setState({
          receivedLocation: true
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Whereas if I remove the update item it works fine.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("storage", event => {
      console.log("Event listener triggered");
      if (event.key === "receivedLocation" && event.newValue === true) {
        this.setState({
          receivedLocation: true
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

I am unable to reset the localstorage and also listen to future changes in the localstorage

Comment: did you post the wrong example in the first code block?  They look identical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The storage events do not fire in [the current document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event). It is used to notify the other open tabs of your app of some change.

> The storage event of the Window interface fires when a storage area
>   (localStorage or sessionStorage) has been modified in the context of
>   another document

If you are trying to notify other components in the current tab, you can use the [`DOMEvents`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) for that.

```
const event = new Event('EVENT_NAME', { detail: { yourPayload }});
window.dispatchEvent(event);

// in your component
window.addEventListener('EVENT_NAME', configChangedHandler, false);

// cleanup
window.removeEventListener('EVENT_NAME', configChangedHandler);
```